# Keydown stopping

Tags: jquery, keydown

I'm using an object to record what arrow keys are being pressed at an instance. While holding down `left` if I then also start holding down `right`, then stop holding down `left` my keydown function still runs, but if I do the same setup but stop holding down `right` instead, the function stops.

Here's the functions:

```
var keys = {};

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    keys[e.which] = true;
    console.log('h');
    moveBall();

});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
    delete keys[e.which];
});

function moveBall(){
    var vals = [];
    var ball = $("#ball1");
    var up = false;
    var down = false;
    var left = false;
    var right = false;
    for( var key in keys ) {
        if ( keys.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            vals.push(key);
        }
    }
    if ($.inArray("39", vals)> -1) right = true; // Right
    if ($.inArray("37", vals)> -1) left = true;
    if ($.inArray("38", vals)> -1) up = true;
    if ($.inArray("40", vals)> -1) down = true;


}
```

Can someone please explain why the ordering of when I stop pressing keys changes whether the `keydown` function still runs?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. Your keydown event stops after 'h' is console-logged no matter which key is pressed. That is because it's simply the end of the function.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so a function runs if at least 1 key is pressed

Comment: Which function? Please post a more complete code :)

Comment: Ok I added my function, and its getting called in the keydown function. Basically I'm going to be moving a ball around a screen depending on which keys are being pressed at that moment. So I need to know if 2 keys are being pressed at once for diagonal movement or just 1 for up/down/left/right movement. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thankyou, i't more clear now. Does moveball() have to be looped?

Comment: Well as long as they're pressing right for example, the ball should keep moving right. I haven't added the actual code for moving, but I'm going to be using the jquery offset() feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you are trying to loop "moveBall" and so actions depending om which key is pressed.

I'm going to change your logic a little bit.

```
//Global object for what keys are active right now.

var keysBeingPressed = {
    right: false,
    left: false,
    up: false,
    down: false
};

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    // Set the right direction = true
    if (e.which == "39") keysBeingPressed.right = true;
    if (e.which == "37") keysBeingPressed.left = true;
    if (e.which == "38") keysBeingPressed.up = true;
    if (e.which == "40") keysBeingPressed.down = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    // Set the right direction = false
    if (e.which == "39") keysBeingPressed.right = false;
    if (e.which == "37") keysBeingPressed.left = false;
    if (e.which == "38") keysBeingPressed.up = false;
    if (e.which == "40") keysBeingPressed.down = false;
});



function moveBall(){
    var ball = $("#ball1");

    // Going left is decreasing X, right is increasing X.
    // Going up is decreasing Y, down increases Y.
    // So, up+left, is diagonal, you move x and y both..
    var movement = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }

    if(keysBeingPressed.right) movement.x++;
    if(keysBeingPressed.left) movement.x--;  //If left+right; x = 1 - 1 = 0 so no movement.
    if(keysBeingPressed.up) movement.y--;
    if(keysBeingPressed.down) movement.y++;

    // add your movement in x/y to top/left
    ball.css({
        top: "+="+movement.y,  //+= adds the value
        left: "+="+movement.x
    });
}

// Loop this function, you want it to run every "animation frame"
setInterval(function(){
    moveBall();
}, 10);
```

I *did* add code to move the ball.

Comment: Wow, I love how there's many ways to solve a problem, but through experience one can figure out an optimal way to write a solution. Your help has really been an eye-opening experience for me that if I stick with coding for a long time eventually I'll be able to see different perspectives of how to go about coding something.

Comment: Glad I could be of help and inspire you :)

Comment: @Roboroads clever solution) What about "Can someone please explain why the ordering of when I stop pressing keys changes whether the keydown function still runs?" OP asks ?

Comment: @MarksCode Is what Andriy is asking still an issue for you? I can't see why an objects order would change..

Comment: No it's ok, I'm sure the way I originally tried to move an object around isn't the best way to do it so I can drop it.